# Flutter: How do i generate a json file from List using GetX package

Tags: json, flutter, listview, dart

How do i generate JSON from multiple lists using GetX package? I am using GetX package for Flutter to pass data between screens in Flutter. The list is obtained from Episode5.dart file. The list is vieewed in MyApp file which is also the place where JSON Generate Button is kept. On clicking the button, i want the json created using the data in the list above. I have the following code:

**1. Episode5.dart**

```
class Episode5 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Episode5State createState() => _Episode5State();
}

class _Episode5State extends State<Episode5> {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

  final form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static var _focusNode = new FocusNode();
  bool update = false;
  int currentIndex = 0;

  List<User> userList = [
    User(name: "a", email: "a"),
    User(name: "d", email: "b"),
    User(name: "c", email: "c"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget bodyData() => DataTable(
          onSelectAll: (b) {},
          sortColumnIndex: 0,
          sortAscending: true,
          columns: <DataColumn>[
            DataColumn(label: Text("Name"), tooltip: "To Display name"),
            DataColumn(label: Text("Email"), tooltip: "To Display Email"),
            DataColumn(label: Text("Update"), tooltip: "Update data"),
          ],
          rows: userList
              .map(
                (user) => DataRow(
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Text(user.name),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(user.email),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          currentIndex = userList.indexOf(user);
                          _updateTextControllers(user); // new function here
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.edit,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Data add to List Table using Form"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            bodyData(),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Form(
                key: form,
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: nameController,
                        focusNode: _focusNode,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        autocorrect: false,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'This field is required';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Name',
                          hintText: 'Name',
                          labelStyle: new TextStyle(
                              decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: emailController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        autocorrect: false,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'This field is required';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Email',
                            hintText: 'Email',
                            labelStyle: new TextStyle(
                                decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid)),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Center(
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    TextButton(
                                      child: Text("Add"),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        form.currentState.save();
                                        addUserToList(
                                          nameController.text,
                                          emailController.text,
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    TextButton(
                                      child: Text("Update"),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        form.currentState.save();
                                        updateForm();
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                      child: Text("Save and Exit"),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        form.currentState.save();
                                        addUserToList(
                                          nameController.text,
                                          emailController.text,
                                        );
                                        Navigator.pop(context, userList);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void updateForm() {
    setState(() {
      User user = User(name: nameController.text, email: emailController.text);
      userList[currentIndex] = user;
    });
  }

  void _updateTextControllers(User user) {
    setState(() {
      nameController.text = user.name;
      emailController.text = user.email;
    });
  }

  void addUserToList(name, email) {
    setState(() {
      userList.add(User(name: name, email: email));
    });
  }
}
```

**1. Main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Testing List View Data From second page to first page"),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: GetBuilder<FormController>(
                  builder: (controller) => ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: controller.userList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        Text(controller.userList[index].name),
                        Text(controller.userList[index].email),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Episode5(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Text("Go to Form"),
              ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              generateJSON();
            },
            child: Text("Generate JSON"),
          ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }

generateJSON() {
    GenerateJSON generate =
        GenerateJSON(controller.userList, controller.schooList);
    String jsonAddress = jsonEncode(generate);
    print(jsonAddress);
  }
    }
```

**2. Model.dart**

```
class User {
  String name;
  String email;

  User({this.name, this.email});

  Map toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'age': email,
      };
}

class GenerateJSON {
  List<User> user;
  List<School> school;

  GenerateJSON([this.user, this.school]);

  Map toJson() {
    List<Map> user =
        this.user != null ? this.user.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList() : null;

    return {'User': user, 'School': school};
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use state management solutions to make data accessible between different screens: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options and use a data class generator like a vscode plugin or freezed to generate toJson and fromJson: https://pub.dev/packages/freezed

Comment: I am using getX to share data between multiple screen. There is no problem in that. I wanted to create a json file when i click on Generate JSON file button. On clicking the button, It will take the data inside list and create a json file.

Comment: create a Map<String,dynamic> based on the values in your list and then use path_provider package's `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` to store it

Comment: @Uni... Can you provide me with documentation or some other means... Because I am completely new to this and i am trying to do. That would mean a lot to me. Thank you for your response :)

Comment: You can always use google to find out tutorials. Here are some links that might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVVCHzkI8as and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62976813/writing-and-reading-json-files-locally-in-flutter-doesnt-include-quotes

Comment: Is your end goal just to store the list that persists after app restart on a button push? Either way, its in your best interest to go through this whole tutorial on json management. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: @Loren.A... Thank you for suggestion. I have done everything to create a json and I became successful at that. Thanks to you. However, I have cam accross 2 problems. I don't know how to get radio button value using GetX Package. and the other is i have posted a question. Can you check it out please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67190050/flutter-how-to-create-a-json-file-using-getx-package

Answer (score 0):

It's exist now a powerful and flexible package on pub.dev named json_bridge.

For those who want to deal with json file, checkout it here: https://pub.dev/packages/json_bridge